# Can't reference to data in v-model in dynamic components via template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

**My VueJs and HTML code below:**

I am getting the error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "tempdt" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

**Can anyone guide me on what mistake I am doing and what is the proper way to reference data from dynamic component?**

```js
const Comp = {
  template: '<div><select v-model="tempdt"><option>hi</option></select><input type="text"  :value="[[tempdt]]" ></input></div>'
}

new Vue({
  delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
  el: "#app",

  data: {
    tempdt: '',
    components: [Comp]
  },

  methods: {
    add() {
      this.components.push(Comp)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="add">Add Component</button>
  <component v-for="(component, index) in components" :key="index" :is="component" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a component using `Vue.component` by giving it a name as first parameter, then move that property to this component.

```js
Vue.component('my-comp', {
  data() {
    return {
      tempdt: '',
    }
  },
  template: '<div><select v-model="tempdt"><option>hi</option></select><input type="text"  :value="[[tempdt]]" ></input></div>'
})
new Vue({
  delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
  el: "#app",

  data: {

    components: ["my-comp"]
  },

  methods: {
    add() {
      this.components.push(Comp)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="add">Add Component</button>
  <component v-for="(component, index) in components" :key="index" :is="component" />
</div>
```